# Windows Server 2008 - Simple Method for Web Request to a Maintenance Page URL?

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, maintenance

I'd like to setup an ASP.NET page that performs some maintenance for a web application.

**What is a simple method for making a web request to the URL for this maintenance page?**

I typically use Windows Tasks for these things, but I don't know how to make a web request within Windows. (`wget` would work on Linux)

I could build an executable that performs the task, but I'd rather not have that dependency.

Comment: It was hard to decide on serverfault or superuser for this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is wget for Windows here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

There is also wfetch for Windows here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21625

I like wfetch and it is very good at doing HTTP Gets.